# Как изменить цвет выделенного текста в классе Text(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Этот код изменяет цвет введенного текста:

```
from tkinter import*

from tkinter.colorchooser import*

def getColor():
    color = askcolor()
    text['fg'] = color[1]

root=Tk()
text=Text(root)
text.pack()

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view= Menu(king,tearoff = 0)

view2=Menu(view,tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Color',command=getColor)

view.add_cascade(label='Text',menu=view2)

king.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

Но мне нужно изменить выбранный текст. Например, мы ввели текст "Здравствуйте, Меня зовут Алекс", изменили цвет всего текста на красный, затем выделели слово "Алекс" и изменили только его цвет. возможно, здесь надо применять `text.bind ('<B1-Motion>')`  `text.tag_add(SEL_FIRST,SEL_LATS)`, но я не знаю, как текст.bin.

Comment: вы хотите цвет поменять пока выделение активно? Если навсегда цвет поменять, то tag добавьте к выделенному диапазону и сконфигурируйте для tag желаемый цвет. Если временно, то у 'sel' tag цвет поменяйте. https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#tags

Comment: да пока выделение активно

Comment: `text.tag_configure('sel', background='yellow')` -- выделяемый текст на жёлтом фоне должен стать (не тестировал)

Comment: Видимо я что-то не так объяснил или вы не так поняли, но мне надо что бы текста менялся цвет текста. То есть вот мы выделили одно слово из предложения через меню вызвали палитру цветов и цвет текста поменялся в зависимости от выбранного цвета. Мы не должны менять цвет выделения текста мы должны поменять цвет именно текста

Comment: для ясности: комментарий это не ответ. В данном случае комментарий это  подсказка: я показал как фон текста поменять. Если этого не достаточно чтобы цвет самого текста поменять, то спрашивайте (на основе вашего же кода, я бы попробовал fg свойство сконфигурировать по аналогии с примером для background свойства)

Comment: То что вы мне предлогаете это не работает. меняется только цвет самого выделителя или текста который выделен, а мне надо что бы я выделел текст выбрал цвет и цвет текста поменялся [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Xnl.gif Мне такое не подходит. Мне надо что бы менялся цвет определенного участока  текста когда мы его выделил

Comment: в вопросе подробно опишите что значит "не работает". Вы сказали: "пока выделение активно" поменять цвет. Приведите код с text.tag_configure и явно укажите чем его поведение от желаемого отличается.

Comment: Блин я не так вас понял мне надо поменять цвет текста навсегда, который мы выделим

Comment: тогда по ссылке посмотрите как `text.tag_add('red', ...)` используется. Индексы выделенного текста текста: `text.tag_ranges(tkinter.SEL)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*

from tkinter.colorchooser import*

def getColor():
    global count
    color = askcolor()
    if text.tag_ranges('sel'):
        text.tag_add('colortag_' + str(count), SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
        text.tag_configure('colortag_' + str(count), foreground=color[1])
        count += 1
    else:
        # Do this if you want to overwrite all selection colors when you change color without selection
        #for tag in text.tag_names():
            #text.tag_delete(tag)
        text.config(foreground=color[1])
count=0   
root=Tk()
text=Text(root)
text.pack()

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view= Menu(king,tearoff = 0)

view2=Menu(view,tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Color',command=getColor)

view.add_cascade(label='Text',menu=view2)

king.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```